# Should I include my .aws-sam file in my repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

Quick question for anyone that is using AWS SAM to deploy their microservices in AWS.
Do you include your .aws-sam files into your repositories? Or do you gitignore this directory and sub directories?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you should not revision control the `.aws-sam` folder(s). Add them to `.gitignore`.

These folders contain intermediate and output files and will, for example, include Python packages, Node modules and other undesirables. None of these should be committed.

Comment: Oddly, the SAM lambda template generator doesn't include this folder in its `.gitignore`, despite it including every other OS/IDE/build file you can imagine.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to include the **.aws-sam** directory in your repository.

The content of this directory are the artifacts outputted from your `sam build` command, and can always be recreated.